# How to select last inserted value of specific column among multiple columns of table in MySQL using PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want select last inserted value of specific column among multiple columns of table in MySQL using PHP.

[image: [enter image description here]]

Comment: MySQL does not keep a searchable journal to keep track of your changes to the database, if that's what you're asking. You'll have to track it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("host_name", "user_name", "password", "db_name");
$mysqli->query("SELECT column_name FROM table_name ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1");
```

Comment: Thanks foe ur reply,
But if last id has empty string/null in specific column, then it should display previous existed value... How?

Comment: SELECT column_name FROM table_name where column_name IS NOT NULL and column_name!= '' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1